# How to navigate to other pages in react, it should start from the top like anchor tag in html, which is the most use in a real web application?

Tags: reactjs, navigation

In my react web app, E-commerce when I clicked to my link to go to other page it stay the same vertical position, I want to achieve this by clicking the link it should start  from the top and I also don't want to use scrollToTop which is not good for my web. Is there any solution to achieve this like an achor tag in html,

It should start from the start or top of the page like anchor tag in HTML

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```ts
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.documentElement || document.body;
    element.scrollTop = 0;
  }, [location]);

  return null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

```ts
import ScrollToTop from './Components/Atoms/ScrollToTop';
import { HashRouter  , Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Test from './Components/Test';
function App() {
  return (
  
 <div className="App">    
        <Header /> 
      <HashRouter>
      <ScrollToTop /> 
        <Switch>    
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>  
        <Route path="/Test" exact component={Test}/> 
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
    
      );
}

export default App;
```

When you click on a link and navigate to another page, the ScrollToTop component will trigger, scrolling the page to the top.